# remove enter mark in varchar column

Tags: mysql

My Data has "enter" mark in one of the columns. How do I remove it and display the text on a single line? phpMyAdmin does show that word on 2 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table set field=replace(field, "\n", "");
```

Comment: I had to do this... update table set field=replace(replace(field, "\n", ""), '\r', '')